# Where in Pakistan can I buy a kettle BBQ?

Tags: equipment, barbecue

I soon will be traveling to Pakistan and I want to do lots of BBQs there.

First I thought about taking a BBQ with me as you can see in the picture:

[image]

But seems like it will be difficult to take it with me, and it might damage in transition.

**Question**

Is there any online/offline place I could buy such a kettle BBQ in Pakistan (Islamabad/Rawalpindi around to be exact).

It would be a bonus to know the price as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy it online. Here's a [decent one.](http://www.kaymu.pk/stainless-steel-barbecue-grill-2166646.html) Here are [cheaper ones](http://www.kaymu.pk/catalog/?q=barbecue) from the same site. Here's [another site](https://www.daraz.pk/catalog/?q=barbecue) with some smaller options.

When we discussed this in chat you told me that you'll be staying with your uncle. The advantage of buying it online is that you can have it shipped to your uncle's address so that it's there even before you arrive. You'll be all ready to fire up the corncobs on the very first day.

[Amazon India](http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=barbecue%20grill) has the hands down best selection, and if they don't ship to Pakistan you can use [this service](https://pkship.com/) to get it delivered. But do be wary of potential customs fees and extended delivery time if you go this route.

You might have to ask your uncle to use one of his payment cards (in case some of these vendors don't accept foreign cards.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this post! I’ll make sure to look into this more!

Answer (score 0):

Most any larger market. Buy 1 large wok, 2 racks to go inside, 1 large lid to go on top. Stop at 1 machine shop. 1 sand box. set on table. You now have a Asian grill. Or you can find the open tray type. Thin & cheap. Or the larger malls look for Ace hardware, Handy Andy, True value. Yes there are some in most larger Asian cities. They normally have 1 or 2 to choose from. They will not be cheap there. I would go with the large wok they last for years, racks can be replaced cheap.